# Why does "Terminal" get replaced with "Applet" in AppleScript?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a simple AppleScript (packed as an app) that tells the Terminal to execute a couple of lines of code. Every so often -- about once every 7 to 10 days -- after a cold restart, the code has been "corrupted" somehow and the word "Terminal" in the Tell statement has been changed to "Applet" and the "do script" commands have been replaced by "«event coredosc»". I've been fixing this by just clicking edit on the error prompt and pasting in the right code for the app. Has anyone encountered this before? None of my other AppleScripts (also packaged as apps) that tell the Terminal to do things has this problem. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've also tried re-typing the app's sourcecode from scratch in a new AppleScript app and no dice.

I am using OS X 10.8.4. Here is the script:

```
set myProcessInfo to do shell script ("ps -x")

if myProcessInfo contains "httpd" and myProcessInfo contains "mysql" then
    do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/stopApache.sh"
    do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/stopMysql.sh"
else
    tell application "Terminal"
            do script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh"
            do script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh > /dev/null"
    end tell
    delay 10
    do shell script "killall Terminal"
end if
```

Comment: Interesting. One thing I'd check when this happens is what the last modified time of the file in question is. Is it what you expect?

Comment: Good suggestion! I hadn't thought of that. I'll check it next time it happens (which may not be for a few days since it happened this morning).

Comment: This has happened again. The file modified date on my app isn't changed. It reports the last modification date was August 26th.

Comment: The change looks so random and weird. I will question the integrity of the file allocation table of your partition.
Could be your script just got some scrambled data from somewhere else?

Comment: @Bichoy I don't think that's very likely. `«event coredosc»` is something I could see showing up in AppleScript somehow (I've gotten errors about a cryptically-named `«class»` before). Steveo, depending on what your script does, you might be able to write a shell script to do it, instead of going through Terminal. If you need it to do other things as well, you might want to look into `do shell script`. It doesn't really answer your question, but it might be a good workaround. :)

Comment: @SteveoDevo Maybe paste the script somewhere so we can see it?

Comment: Thanks all. I've added the script. I use do script because for some reason when I wrote this many moons ago I couldn't get MAMP to start when using do shell script. (The point of the script is to start/stop MAMP without requiring the input of a username/password.)

Comment: Instead of killing the Terminal, can you just `tell` it to quit? Maybe pulling the plug is triggering some emergency behavior.

Comment: It makes me wonder if somewhere on your system there's something called "Applet" that also advertises support for the core/dosc AppleEvent, just like Terminal.app does. Or, if maybe Terminal.app is not properly advertising support for that event. Does the file `/Application/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/Resources/Terminal.sdef` exist on your system, and is it properly formed (not damaged/corrupted)? That's Terminal.app's scripting definitions file, where its AppleScript/AppleEvent support is defined. Does Terminal's info.plist exist and is properly formed? Does it reference the .sdef file?

Comment: Yes, it does look like you can use `do shell script` instead of `tell application "Terminal"`. That wouldn't kill the start scripts if they weren't finished after ten seconds, too. Avoiding `tell`ing Terminal might fix your problem, too.

Comment: And if `do shell script` doesn't like the `>` redirect, you can wrap the entire thing in a `sh` invocation, like so: `do shell script "sh -c '/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh >/dev/null'"`

Comment: Alternately, as I suggested before, you could rewrite the entire thing as a shell script. If the Apache and MySQL daemons have an `/etc/init.d`-like script that allows you to check their statuses, you could use them in the shell script. That IMO is a better solution altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you would fix whatever's messing up the script, but you can work around it by using a shell script instead:

```
#!/bin/sh

tempfile=$(mktemp /tmp/XXXXXXXXXX)
ps -x >$tempfile

if grep httpd $tempfile && grep mysql $tempfile
then
    /Applications/MAMP/bin/stopApache.sh
    /Applications/MAMP/bin/stopMysql.sh
else
    /Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh
    /Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh >/dev/null
fi

rm -f $tempfile
```

As I mentioned in the comments, if you have scripts for Apache and MySQL that exit successfully if the respective daemons are running and nonsuccessfully otherwise, you can use those instead of writing `ps` output to a temporary file and `grep`ping it.

Alternately, you could use a modified version of your original AppleScript, using only `do shell script` and not `tell application "Terminal" to do script`:

```
set myProcessInfo to do shell script ("ps -x")

if myProcessInfo contains "httpd" and myProcessInfo contains "mysql" then
    do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/stopApache.sh"
    do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/stopMysql.sh"
else
    do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh"
    do shell script "/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh > /dev/null"
end if
```